# Loop to fill matrix in Python

Tags: python, loops, matrix, data-structures

In the row, where it does `diabetes_x = diabetes.data[:, np.newaxis, 0]`it selects one of 20 features from this diabetes data structure as a vector.
A part of this x-vector is fed to the machine learning function and the other part is used for testing.

In the end it feeds these test x-vectors to a prediction function to obtain `y_predict=regr.predict(diabetes_x_train)`.

The question is: How can you loop this, so that you obtain matrices instead of vectors to fill in ALL the 20 features?

For example:

`diabetes_x` is `mxn` => `diabetes_x_train`, `diabetes_x_test` are `mxn`
    `y_predict` is `mxn`

This is the python code:

```
from sklearn import linear_model # Machine Learning tool
import numpy as np # Mathematics and Linear Algebra tool
import pandas as pd # data structure tool
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt # scientific plotting tool
import seaborn as sns # # scientific plotting tool
%matplotlib inline

### Linear Regression example
from sklearn import datasets, linear_model

# Load the diabetes dataset
diabetes = datasets.load_diabetes()
# Use only one feature
diabetes_x = diabetes.data[:, np.newaxis, 0] # change 0 to something else for other features
# Split the data into training/testing sets
diabetes_x_train = diabetes_x[:-20]
diabetes_x_test = diabetes_x[-20:]
# Split the targets into training/testing sets
diabetes_y_train = diabetes.target[:-20]
diabetes_y_test = diabetes.target[-20:]
# Create linear regression object
regr = linear_model.LinearRegression()
# Train the model using the training sets
regr.fit(diabetes_x_train, diabetes_y_train)
# Obtain prediction based on previous experience
y_predict=regr.predict(diabetes_x_train)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this to select all the 10 features (there are total 10 of them at least the `sklearn 0.18.1` and `python 2.7` i am using on windows):

```
diabetes_x = diabetes.data[:, range(10)] # select 10 features
# Split the data into training/testing sets
diabetes_x_train = diabetes_x[:-20,:]
print diabetes_x_train.shape
# (422L, 10L)
diabetes_x_test = diabetes_x[-20:,:]
print diabetes_x_test.shape
# (20L, 10L)
# Split the targets into training/testing sets
diabetes_y_train = diabetes.target[:-20]
diabetes_y_test = diabetes.target[-20:]
# Create linear regression object
regr = linear_model.LinearRegression()
# Train the model using the training sets
regr.fit(diabetes_x_train, diabetes_y_train)
# Obtain prediction based on previous experience
y_predict=regr.predict(diabetes_x_test)
#print y_predict

plt.plot(range(len(diabetes.target)), diabetes.target, 'r-', label='test')
plt.plot(range(len(diabetes_y_train), len(diabetes.target)), y_predict, 'g-', label='predict')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Do you feed all the 10 features to the same linear regression modell 'regr'? Or does python automatically make a separate one for each input-output-pair?

Comment: The number of columns of the `diabetes_x_train` dataset is 10 (that you can see from the `shape` printed) which is the number of features in the training data. If you provide this dataset in the `sklearn` fit function, all the 10 features will automatically be considered.